# cobertura on maven multi module project

Tags: maven-2, cobertura

I have a Maven project with 4 modules - 3 of them contain code and some tests (testing equals and hashcode of the classes) whereas the 4th module is for testing the 3 other modules.

Now I want to run the cobertura code coverage tool to get an overview which classes are well tested and which are not. I did some investigations on that topic and it seems that cobertura is not aware of generating the right code coverage percentages and line coverages, if some sources which are tested are located within other modules.

I have read over some links like [SeamTestCoverageWithCobertura](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/SeamTestCoverageWithCobertura) and [Using the plugin Coverage within a multi-module Maven 2](http://foobar.lacoctelera.net/post/2008/09/15/uso-del-plugin-cobertura-dentro-un-proyecto-multi-modulo-en) but there has to be an out of the box solution. Can anybody report some new directions on this topic? Or are there bether tools like cobertura? I've stumbled upon emma but this tool does not offer line coverage...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of version 2.6, there is an aggregate option that can be set to true in the parent pom:

```
<reporting>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>./target/tmpCobertura</outputDirectory>
        <formats>
            <format>html</format>
        </formats>
        <aggregate>true</aggregate>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: IMHO this should become the accepted answer since both issues mentioned in the accepted answer are fixed since 2.5.

Comment: This can also be done via command line only:
`mvn cobertura:cobertura -Dcobertura.aggregate=true -Dcobertura.report.format=xml`

You can change the report format as you wish.

According to the cobertura maven plugin's github repo, this feature is available 
[since v2.5](https://github.com/mojohaus/cobertura-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/cobertura/CoberturaReportMojo.java#L126) (commit [64a8823](https://github.com/mojohaus/cobertura-maven-plugin/commit/64a8823866b4c8be74a44383162088d616c65185#diff-e4171be1b77f9a9b331e21a0661c1433R126)).

Comment: but not sure why the coverage result always 0 by this "aggregate" way

Comment: Even after having <aggregate>true</aggregate> I do not get consolidated report. What else should I verify? In fact my project is using cobertura version 2.7, which claims to have resolved multi module project issue by default.

Comment: Not getting an aggregate coverage in cobertura version 2.7 with aggregate=true.Does anyone know what is wrong with the setup?

Answer (score 9):

We don't have sonar here and right now, we cant install it. So i had to find a workaround and got one. This solution works with a simple `mvn clean install -DrunCobertura=true` in a multi module project. You only need to add this profile to your `super pom.xml` of your project, define the `working.dir` property and it should work.

```
<profile>
    <id>runCobertura</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>runCobertura</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <cobertura.format>html</cobertura.format>
        <cobertura.working.dir>${working.dir}/${project.version}/cobertura</cobertura.working.dir>
        <cobertura.complete.ser.file>${cobertura.working.dir}/complete.ser</cobertura.complete.ser.file>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>.</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>cobertura.ser</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                                <directory>${cobertura.working.dir}</directory>
                            </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>cobertura-Instrument</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <taskdef resource="tasks.properties"/>
                                <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
                                <if>
                                    <available file="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
                                    <then>
                                        <cobertura-instrument>
                                            <fileset dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}">
                                                <include name="**/*.class"/>
                                            </fileset>
                                        </cobertura-instrument>
                                    </then>
                                </if>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>cobertura-createCombinedSerFile</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <taskdef resource="tasks.properties"/>
                                <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
                                <if>
                                    <available file="${cobertura.complete.ser.file}"/>
                                    <then>
                                        <cobertura-merge datafile="${basedir}/tmp.ser">
                                            <fileset file="${cobertura.complete.ser.file}"/>
                                            <fileset file="${basedir}/cobertura.ser"/>
                                        </cobertura-merge>
                                        <move file="${basedir}/tmp.ser" tofile="${basedir}/cobertura.ser"/>
                                    </then>
                                </if>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>cobertura-copyResultSerFileAndSources</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <taskdef resource="tasks.properties"/>
                                <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
                                <if>
                                    <available file="${basedir}/cobertura.ser"/>
                                    <then>
                                        <move file="${basedir}/cobertura.ser" tofile="${cobertura.complete.ser.file}"/>
                                        <mkdir dir="${cobertura.working.dir}/source"/>
                                        <if>
                                            <available file="${basedir}/src/main/java"/>
                                            <then>
                                                <copy todir="${cobertura.working.dir}/source">
                                                    <fileset dir="src/main/java">
                                                        <include name="**/*.java"/>
                                                    </fileset>
                                                </copy>
                                            </then>
                                        </if>
                                        <cobertura-report datafile="${cobertura.complete.ser.file}" format="${cobertura.format}" destdir="${cobertura.working.dir}/report">
                                            <fileset dir="${cobertura.working.dir}/source"/>
                                        </cobertura-report>
                                    </then>
                                </if>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.4.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
                        <version>20020829</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>
```

What does it do:

**1.** `@process-classes`-Instrument the compiled classes of the module.

**2.** `@generate-test-sources`-Merges the `.ser` file from previous modules with the created one of this module to get the complete code coverage.

**3.** `@test`-Creates the code coverage report. Should be called in the last module, but due to the fact that the last module can change, i call it always and the previous reports will be overwritten. If you use the report in `xml` format (for Jenkins) it's fast, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 8):

According to [MCOBERTURA-65](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOBERTURA-65), the maven cobertura plugin still doesn't know how to aggregate reports of sub-modules into a consolidated one. Some work has been done to implement a `merge` target on the maven cobertura plugin (see [MCOBERTURA-33](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOBERTURA-33)) but this code hasn't been included in the plugin yet. I didn't test the patch myself and can't say if it's worth a try.

In consequence, lots of people indeed suggest to use the maven [dashboard plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/dashboard-maven-plugin/) but I'd personally stay far away from it as it isn't very satisfying on the long term and I faced lots of issues with it (technical problems, lost of history,...). Instead, **I warmly recommend [Sonar](http://sonar.codehaus.org/)**. Have a look at [Nemo](http://nemo.sonar.codehaus.org/), a public instance of the last version of Sonar, for a live demo of this tool. See for example the [Commons Digester](http://nemo.sonarsource.org/project/index/commons-digester:commons-digester) project and the [drill down of code coverage](http://nemo.sonarsource.org/drilldown/measures/51834?metric=coverage).

Comment: That's why I added a link to Nemo. Check for example http://nemo.sonarsource.org/project/index/commons-digester:commons-digester and the drill down: http://nemo.sonarsource.org/drilldown/measures/51834?metric=coverage

Comment: Sonar will not show that code in the first three modules is covered by code in the fourth module.  It simply aggregates the 4 completely separate and incomplete reports.

Comment: Sonar doesn't allow you to control code coverage against a threshold, as part of a build lifecycle, as far as I understand..

Answer (score 3):

There are a few plugins that aggregate Cobertura (and other) reports. Check out the [sonar](http://sonar.codehaus.org/) and [XRadar](http://xradar.sourceforge.net/reports/dynamics/index.html) plugins. There is also the [dashboard plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/dashboard-maven-plugin/), but it is a bit clunky.

FWIW Emma does do [line coverage](http://emma.sourceforge.net/intro.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would really like to thank Sven Oppermann for submitting his runCobertura profile solution. This helped
me solve the question of 'how do you get aggregate coverage reports for multi-module  projects when you might not be 
able to use Sonar.

I have created an example which demonstrates  how to create multi-module projects which produce  code coverage reports that assess not only unit test coverage (in all submodules), but also  coverage on INTEGRATION TESTS THAT BRING
UP YOUR APPLICATION AS A .WAR IN JETTY.     The example is hosted here:

```
        http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9940067/code/multi-module-cobertura.zip
```

The recipe I am providing is pretty re-useable if you copy the runCobertura profile listed below (based on the one
provide by Sven.)

Here are some notes which will help you use this profile:

- the integration test module that launches jetty (and defines tests that run against 
    the production .war) must either be named web-test-driver-for-code-coverage, or you 
     must modify the  statements in the runCobertura configuration block.
- your coverage reports will appear wherever you set your  variable
- you MUST include 'clean' on the command line when you run your build for code coverage. 'clean' will blow away prior cobertura.ser files, 
    which if left lurking around can cause very confusing reports to be 
     generated (a sign you need to 'clean' is that the reports show 
    100% coverage for everything, including stuff you know is never called.

  ```
    mvn -PrunCobertura clean install      # gives you the aggregate reports.
  ```
- the module  web-test-driver-for-code-coverage defines a servlet context listener that explicitly flushes the cobertura metrics to disk
    when the web server shuts down.  Supposedly the container is supposed to do this automatically, but that didn't work for me, so 
    I had to hook in the explicit call to flush out the metrics.
- the integration tests are done in groovy because i based this on some maven project skeletons that already used groovy.
    Sorry for the added clutter, but it does show you how to do your tests in groovy (which is highly recommended anyway.)
- Note that when you compile with the runCobertura  profile all of your artifacts are created with cobertura instrumentation, even your 
    .war file.  You NEVER want to let this get out in production of course (for one thing it would run realllll slow.)  I have not 
    yet figured out a food way to get the artifacts to rename themselves so that the 'cobertura-ness' is obvious.

  ```
  <profiles>
  <profile>
      <id>runCobertura</id>
      <activation>
          <property>
              <name>runCobertura</name>
              <value>true</value>
          </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
          <cobertura.format>html</cobertura.format>
          <working.dir>/tmp</working.dir>
          <cobertura.working.dir>${working.dir}/${project.version}/cobertura</cobertura.working.dir>
          <cobertura.complete.ser.file>${cobertura.working.dir}/complete.ser</cobertura.complete.ser.file>

          <!-- scope which determines whether or not cobertura is included in .war file: overriden here -->
          <cobertura.dependency.scope>compile</cobertura.dependency.scope>
      </properties>
      <build>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.4.1</version>
                  <inherited>false</inherited>
                  <configuration>
                      <filesets>
                          <fileset>
                              <directory>.</directory>
                              <includes>
                                  <include>**/cobertura.ser</include>
                              </includes>
                          </fileset>
                          <fileset>
                                  <directory>${cobertura.working.dir}</directory>
                              </fileset>
                      </filesets>
                  </configuration>
              </plugin>




              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>1.7</version>
                  <executions>
                      <execution>
                          <id>cobertura-Instrument</id>
                          <phase>process-classes</phase>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>run</goal>
                          </goals>
                          <configuration>
                              <target>
                                  <taskdef resource="tasks.properties"/>
                                  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
                                  <echo message="::PROCESS CLASSES: ${artifactId}"/>

                                  <if>
                                    <equals arg1="${artifactId}" arg2="web-test-driver-for-code-coverage" />
                                      <then>
                                          <echo message="::SKIPPING PHASE for integration test"/>
                                      </then>
                                      <else>
                                          <if>
                                              <available file="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
                                              <then>
                                                  <echo message="::BEFORE INSTRUMENT"/>
                                                  <cobertura-instrument>
                                                      <fileset dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}">
                                                          <include name="**/*.class"/>
                                                      </fileset>
                                                  </cobertura-instrument>
                                              </then>
                                          </if>
                                      </else>
                                  </if>


                              </target>
                          </configuration>
                      </execution>
                      <execution>
                          <id>cobertura-createCombinedSerFile</id>
                          <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>run</goal>
                          </goals>
                          <configuration>
                              <target>
                                  <taskdef resource="tasks.properties"/>
                                  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
                                  <echo message=":::generate-test-sources"/>


                                  <if>
                                    <equals arg1="${artifactId}" arg2="web-test-driver-for-code-coverage" />
                                      <then>
                                          <echo message="::SHORT CIRCUIT COMBINE PHASE for integration test"/>
                                          <echo  message="source - ${cobertura.complete.ser.file} dest - ${basedir}/cobertura.ser"/>
                                          <copy file="${cobertura.complete.ser.file}" tofile="${basedir}/cobertura.ser"/>
                                      </then>
                                      <else>
                                          <if>
                                              <available file="${basedir}/cobertura.ser"/>
                                              <then>
                                                  <echo message="::: Is available ${basedir}/cobertura.ser"/>
                                              </then>
                                          </if>

                                          <if>
                                              <available file="${cobertura.complete.ser.file}"/>
                                              <then>
                                                  <echo message="before merge1"/>
                                                  <cobertura-merge datafile="${basedir}/tmp.ser">
                                                      <fileset file="${cobertura.complete.ser.file}"/>
                                                      <fileset file="${basedir}/cobertura.ser"/>
                                                  </cobertura-merge>
                                                  <echo message="move temp.ser to ${basedir}/cobertura.ser"/>
                                                  <move file="${basedir}/tmp.ser" tofile="${basedir}/cobertura.ser"/>
                                              </then>
                                          </if>
                                      </else>
                                  </if>
                              </target>
                          </configuration>
                      </execution>
                      <execution>
                          <id>cobertura-copyResultSerFileAndSources</id>
                          <phase>verify</phase>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>run</goal>
                          </goals>
                          <configuration>
                              <target>
                                  <taskdef resource="tasks.properties"/>
                                  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>

                                  <echo message=":::copyResultSerFileAndSources -beforeIf"/>
                                  <if>
                                      <available file="${basedir}/cobertura.ser"/>
                                      <then>
                                          <echo message="move1"/>
                                          <move file="${basedir}/cobertura.ser" tofile="${cobertura.complete.ser.file}"/>
                                          <mkdir dir="${cobertura.working.dir}/source"/>
                                          <if>
                                              <available file="${basedir}/src/main/java"/>
                                              <then>
                                                  <copy todir="${cobertura.working.dir}/source">
                                                      <fileset dir="src/main/java">
                                                          <include name="**/*.java"/>
                                                      </fileset>
                                                  </copy>
                                              </then>
                                          </if>
                                          <echo message="runreport"/>
                                          <cobertura-report datafile="${cobertura.complete.ser.file}" format="${cobertura.format}" destdir="${cobertura.working.dir}/report">
                                              <fileset dir="${cobertura.working.dir}/source"/>
                                          </cobertura-report>
                                      </then>
                                  </if>
                              </target>
                          </configuration>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
                  <dependencies>
                      <dependency>
                          <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
                          <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
                          <version>1.9.4.1</version>
                      </dependency>
                      <dependency>
                          <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
                          <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
                          <version>20020829</version>
                      </dependency>
                  </dependencies>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </build>
      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
              <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
              <version>1.9.4.1</version>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>
  </profile>
  </profiles>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Thomas Sundberg offers an interesting solution in which instrumentation and test reporting is done via `ant`, but all testing and dependency management via `mvn`.

Check Here: [thomassundberg wordpress](http://thomassundberg.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/test-coverage-in-a-multi-module-maven-project/)

It means that you have to execute the commands below at the parent level in this order:

```
mvn clean compile
ant instrument
mvn test
ant report
```

Integrating these steps into `sonar` is described by Martijn Stelinga.

[test-coverage-in-multi-module-projects](http://www.chess-ix.com/2012/09/17/test-coverage-in-multi-module-projects/)

Answer (score 0):

I could implement something quite similar to what you need thanks to this answer: [Maven - add dependency on artifact source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007211/maven-add-dependency-on-artifact-source/1010634#1010634)

I just added `<classifier>sources</classifier>` and cobertura includes classes from dependencies as well.

Regards.