# Cobertura and Jetty

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, code-coverage, cobertura

I'm trying to get coverage report when running my webapp on Jetty, using cobertura.
We already have cobertura running for unit-tests by using the surefire plugin.
We also have the failsafe plugin configured for running our integration-tests.

I've already (manually) instrumented my war and deployed it.

When running `mvn verify` with integration-tests only profile, it seems cobertura is working because I get all kind of new warnings in eclipse console (i'm running jetty from there) probably because byte-code was changed by cobertura.
But I don't get the `.ser` file to be written, even when calling `"stop"` on the jetty server.

I do get a `.ser` file when running `mvn cobertura:cobertura` and a report is generated under `target/site` directory of my webapp. The report shows 0% coverage because `cobertura:cobertura` doesn't run any tests.

How can I run my integration-tests using the failsafe make cobertura to work?
Any other suggestions?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 5):

I solved this issue by using [cobertura-it](http://code.google.com/p/cobertura-it-maven-plugin/) plugin. It extends the original cobertura plugin and allows to use report-only goal. In addition, I must run two separate commands (see below) to test and generate reports (merging to 1 command does not work). Here is my plugin configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-it-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <formats>
            <format>html</format>
        </formats>
        <check>
            <haltOnFailure>false</haltOnFailure>
        </check>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>cobertura</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>            
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.2.v20110526</version>
    <configuration>
        <stopKey>aaaaaaaaaaaaa</stopKey>
        <stopPort>8085</stopPort>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <daemon>true</daemon>
                <classesDirectory>target/generated-classes/cobertura</classesDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
              <id>integration-test</id>
              <phase>integration-test</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
              </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>verify</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

So I run this:
`mvn clean verify`

Note that after Jetty is stopped, there is some cobertura messages:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 minute 13 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Nov 13 12:58:29 ICT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 86M/204M
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
2011-11-13 12:58:29.765:WARN::4 threads could not be stopped
Flushing results...
Flushing results done
Cobertura: Loaded information on 342 classes.
Cobertura: Saved information on 342 classes.
```

Finally, I use `mvn site` to generate reports. Here is my report configuration

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- An error on version 2.8 -->
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportsDirectories>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/failsafe-reports</reportsDirectory>
                </reportsDirectories>
            </configuration>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>report-only</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- An error that takes long time to generate this report -->
                <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
            </configuration>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>dependencies</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-it-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>html</format>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>report-only</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need some `<execution>` tag to your `cobertura-maven-plugin` plugin config.
There are some examples on http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/instrumentingDeploymentArtifact.html but this answer looks better: [What is the proper way to use Cobertura with Maven 3.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931360/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-cobertura-with-maven-3-0-2/6932567#6932567)